# How to create list of files containing only filename in one set_fact task

Tags: replace, ansible

In Ansible 2.9 I am trying to create a list of files using the lookup plugin with the fileglob parameter that contains only the names of the files (not the path) and can be done in a single set_fact. My problem seems to be that I cannot figure out how to properly use regex when calling the replace method. I'm probably confusing some of the terminology there.

This is what I have so far, and once this works was going to send to split to build list.

```
- name: compile list of template files
  set_fact:
    list_of_files: "{{ lookup('fileglob', 'mydir/*').replace('/', '') }}"
```

But I cannot get any wildcard or regex I try to work. I have tried dozens of different options, that probably aren't worth repeating here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first split the result of `lookup` into a list with `.split()`. Then you can pass it to `map` and there `regex_replace` everything up to the last slash inside each list element.

So try this:

```yaml
- name: compile list of template files
  set_fact:
    list_of_files: "{{ lookup('fileglob', 'mydir/*').split(',') | map('regex_replace', '.*/', '') | list }}"
```

The `replace` method you used does not handle regex. You have to use `regex_replace` but that is not a python function but a jinja filter so you  have to use the "jinja pipe operator" `|` to pass data to it and not the "python dot operator".  (Actually you pass the data to the jinja `map` filter.)

Comment: I get `"msg": "<generator object do_map at 0x7fcd9322b500>"` as the error message when I try that. - EDIT as the output from debug-walking the list afterwards.

Comment: sorry,forgott a `|list`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a  non-regex solution using `basename` filer, this would use ansible's in-built logic to filter out the file name from the full path.

```
- name: compile list of template files
  set_fact:
    list_of_files: "{{ lookup('fileglob', 'mydir/*').split(',')|map('basename') |list}}"
```

`map` function feeds on an iterable(in this case output of lookup and split) and applies the function inside `map` (in this case `basename`) to all the elements of the iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Map [basename](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names) filter and use *query* instead of *lookup*. The query creates a list by default. For example, the task below does the job

```yaml
    - name: compile list of template files
      set_fact:
        list_of_files: "{{ query('fileglob', 'mydir/*')|
                           map('basename')|list }}"
```